# How to work with a Visual Studio 2017 Solution with 650+ projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I must work with a Visual Studio (2017) Solution that contains 654 projects, and counting. The projects are a mixture of C++ and C# projects - possibly 2/3 C++.

The problem is, VS2017 (we're already running 15.8) is highly unstable at this project count, but for some tasks I need to open the whole solution.

One can (and should) question the design, but please not here. Are there any viable tricks to make working with such a `sln` bearable?

The *problems* we have is:

- *After* having fully loaded, it's sluggish as hell, even on our beefy dev machines. Hangs often.
- It will crash many times a day. (We isolated a few cases that reliably crash it, like oping the C++ setting dialog, but it's still unstable).

  - Crashes are often observed when VS peaks at ~ 2.6GB RAM

**Not** Problems:

- Solution load times: The solution is loaded in a decent amount of time. We don't need to optimize for this at the moment.
- Compilation times: Devs don't do full-solution builds anyway. (But some tasks require having your corner in the full context of the whole solution.)

I already tried disabling VS Intellisense, but it didn't help. Disabling our VisualAssistX plugin also didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Historically the VS team has always said that they're going to fix the problem of VS loading too much at some indefinite point in time. That's one reason why they 
haven't made it 64-bit yet as well. Now that they've disabled the selective loading API, you're pretty much on their mercy.

For older VS versions, there's [Funnel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DimitriDering.Funnel).

It allows you to selectively load a subset of the projects, automatically loading dependencies. The added benefit is that refactoring, search etc. only works in context of loaded projects, making it much faster. You can also save and organize your filters, making it easier to switch between different subsets.

Comment: Quote: WARNING: The development of this extension is discontinued. The VS 2017 API interface used by vsFunnel for filtering projects at load time is no longer supported by Microsoft